# React Router v4 relative path build folder

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a question and problem.

So when I build my React app all stuff is in build folder, and this stuff needs to be pasted into server. But in my case I have something different.

URL that app will be server in browser will be

http://url.url.com:4000/folder-name-where-react-build stuff-will-be/my-routes

example:
http://google.com:4000/tracer/counter

tracer is folder on the server where stuff from react build will be

how to see my routing to have this tracer thing be recoginzed?

`basename='/tracer'`??

thanks

Comment: Have you tried setting the [`basename` of `BrowserRouter`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter/basename-string) to `/tracer`?

Comment: i will try, but when i set basename=tracer and buld stuff and run serve -s build it is getting 404

Comment: Even if you visit `/tracer` in the browser?

Comment: yes, but app starts so localhost:5000 is rendering but localhost:5000/tracer/nav is 404